# Undefined property: stdClass:: error in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5.1

I got an error when i trying to print a value of an array in my Laravel Application.Please take a look.

**My Controller:**

```
public function index()
{
    //
    $data = new Userflow();
    $result = $data->gobalsCount();
    $res = $data->yrLogins;
    $res1 = $data->mnLogins;
    $res2 = $data->dayLogins;
    $res3 = $data->hrLogins;
    $res4 = $data->minLogins;
    $res5 = $data->secLogins;
    $object = [$res,$res1,$res2,$res3,$res4,$res5];

   //dd($object);
    return view('userflow',compact('object'));
}
```

**My Model:**

```
public $yrLogins = "";
public function gobalsCount(){
    $this->yrLogins = DB::SELECT("SELECT count(*)/(TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,'2016-01-01 00:00:00',now())+1) as avg from authtracker  where created_at >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00'");
................
```

**My blade template:**

```
  @foreach($object as $value)
  <td>{{ $value['0']->avg }}</td>                 
  @endforeach
```

In this way i got this type of error.If i `var_dump($object)` then it returns:

```
array:6 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    0 => {#1396 ▼
      +"avg": "2.0000"
    }
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▶]
  2 => array:1 [▶]
  3 => array:1 [▶]
  4 => array:1 [▶]
  5 => array:1 [▶]
]
```

How can i print this `array` value `ex: 2.0000`.
Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: may be it is like this {{ $value[0][0]['avg'] }}

Comment: @Jaimin i have tried this way its throw me `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array` this error.

Comment: Try like this {{ $value['0']['avg'] }}

Comment: @Komal same error `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

Comment: Can you plz print value var_dump($value)

Comment: @Komal it returns `array:1 [▼
  0 => {#1396 ▼
    +"avg": "2.0000"
  }
]`

Comment: Can you update your methods (yrLogins and the others) to return arrays instead of objects ?

Comment: @MarcBrillault i don't understand what you say.Could you tell me again?

Comment: Are you sure you have `avg` property in every object?

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud if your method returns 0 => ["avg" => "2.0000"] instead of 0 => {"avg": "2.0000"}, you should be able to get it with {{ $value['0']['avg'] }}

I May be wrong, since Blade should work with objects and arrays

Comment: In other words you have `as avg` in every request? Ok. What `dd($object[0][0]);` output in Controller?

Comment: @aleksejjj its returns `{#1396 ▼
  +"avg": "2.0000"
}`

Comment: What about `dd($object[0][0]->avg)`?

Comment: Its `"2.0000"`....But how can i get all 6 value throw `foreach` loop?

Comment: Just check another values `$object[1][0]->avg` `$object[2][0]->avg`.. I believe you have empty variable.. Because your foreach loop looks correct

Comment: @aleksejjj Ok.I have find a solution from your comments.Thanks.

Comment: It's my pleasure.

Answer (score -1):

May be try this way,

```
@foreach($object as $value)
  <td>{{$value[0][0]->avg}}</td>                 
@endforeach
```

Haven't tried, but should work.

Comment: Not working.Error: `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`